# 'find' (command) finds nothing with -wholename

Tags: linux, bash, directory, find

Why does this command work:

```
/home/user1/tmp $ find ./../.. -wholename '.*/tmp/file.c' -exec echo '{}' \;
./../../user2/tmp/file.c
/home/user1/tmp $
```

And this command does not work? (finds nothing)

```
/home/user1/tmp $ find /home -wholename '.*/tmp/file.c' -exec echo '{}' \;
/home/user1/tmp $
```

Comment: How did you conclude it do not work ? What is your error message, please post it?

Comment: The `#` symbol shows the linux prompt. (edited)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first command generates file names starting with `./../..`. Thus the wholename pattern will match because they start with `.`.

The second command generates filenames starting with `/home`. However, the wholename pattern is still looking for paths starting with `.` which will not match any file in this case.

Note that patterns are *not* regular expressions. If you were expecting them, look at the `-regex` option instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks! To be perfect, add this to your answer: `root@camel:/home/user1/tmp# find /home -wholename '*/tmp/file.c' -exec echo '{}' \;`